# Obtain version of Akka HTTP at run time

Tags: scala, akka-http

My server is built on top of Akka HTTP. If I don't set the `Server` header, the externally configurable default of `akka-http/10.1.8` will be automatically added by Akka. I know how to override that with my own server by adding the `respondWithHeaders` directive around my entire routs tree:

```
   respondWithHeaders(Server(myProductVersion)) {
      // my routs here
   }
```

This works as expected; the Server response header now reads my product. What I want though is to include akka's header as well, as I like it and don't mind telling the world about my server stack. Given the signature of the `Server.apply` method, I should be able to do that like so:

```
   respondWithHeaders(Server(myProductVersion, akkaProductVersion)) {
      // my routs here
   }
```

... my problem is that I can't figure out how to get at that `akkaProductVersion` object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading `akka.http.version` configuration property like so

```
system.settings.config.getString("akka.http.version")
```

so you could try

```
Server(
  myProductVersion, 
  system.settings.config.getString("akka.http.version")
)
```

According to [default configuration](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html#configuration)

```
    # The default value of the `Server` header to produce if no
    # explicit `Server`-header was included in a response.
    # If this value is the empty string and no header was included in
    # the request, no `Server` header will be rendered at all.
    server-header = akka-http/${akka.http.version}
```

We can see how akka-http reads `server-header` when constructing `ServerSettings` [here](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/0ca2724a24b3729394e52493b210e48d6ac8dcac/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/impl/settings/ServerSettingsImpl.scala#L76):

```
c.getString("server-header").toOption.map(Server(_)),
```

Comment: Thanks, Mario. I suppose it is unreasonable of me to expect the ready-made default Server object be exposed to the client code and this seems exactly the right way to instantiate it on my own.